# CSS alignment doesn't work on different devices

Tags: html, css

I have a website written in php(html) and css, and my problem is, that sometimes(usually after redirecting), css alignment breaks, and everything, except header picture, moves to top left corner. On my computer (even that, I am already talking about site uploaded on host server) I can solve this by refreshing page, and suddenly everything is just the way it should be. On different devices (I have tried it on 2 different computers and 3 phones), it is never shown the right way. I have tried this on different browsers (firefox, chrome, phone browsers...) but it didn't make any difference, so obviously the problem is my coding :D
If anyone is interested, i am posting my css code, if not, simply skip it.

```css
body{
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12pt;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
}
#page{
 overflow: auto;
 background: #B6B1B1 url('img/background.JPG') no-repeat center;
 background-attachment: fixed;
}
img{
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
 width: auto\9;
}
#languages li a{
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #191045;
}
#languages li a:hover{
 color: #E49900;
}
h1 a span{
 display: none;
}
h1 a{
 width: 100%;
 height: 240px;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 background: transparent url('img/headerpic.png') no-repeat top center;
}
#menubar{
 width: 70%;
 position: absolute;
 margin: 220 15% 0 15%;
 text-align: center;
}
#menu li{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
 margin-top: 20;
 margin-left: 5px;
 padding: 0 15 0 15;
 background-color: rgba(25,16,69,0.85);
 border-radius: 5px; 
}
#menu .selected{
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 3px;
 border-color: rgba(25,16,69,0.85); 
}
#menu .selected a{
 color: rgba(25,16,69,0.85);
}
#menu li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: white;
}
#menu li a:hover{
 color: #E49900;
}

#main{
 min-height: 350;
 position: relative; 
 display:block;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-right: 15%;
 margin-top: 340;
 padding: 15 15 15 15;
 border-radius: 10px;
 color: black; 
}
footer{
 position: relative;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.85);
 width: 70%;
 margin-left: 15%;
 margin-right: 15%;
 margin-top: 15;
 padding: 2.5 15 2.5 15;
 border-radius: 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 bottom: 5px;
 color: black;
 font-size: 80%;
 text-align: center;
}
#footer a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: black;
}
#footer a:hover{
 color: #E49900;
}
```

Thank you for all the tips :)

Comment: Try to make your question more concise only including what you need to; not too many people want to read those walls of text and code.

Comment: fix your css: `width: auto\9;`. auto9?

Comment: @AnthonyAstige I am sorry, if it is too long, I just wanted to explain it in detail, because usually are people telling me, that my explanations are not very helpful... and now I dont know what to skip :D

Comment: @MarcB sorry, can you explain more closely?

Comment: Do you have any javascript on this site? Besides @MarcB's point about the invalid css, the fact that refreshing makes any difference suggests to me there might be a script problem

Comment: @henry I am not using javascript... and it (somehow) makes difference only on my pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, my "Oh such a big mistake" was, that I didn't write units behind the number in margin, padding and so on... I simply wrote for example 10. When I added px/em... behind it, suddenly everything worked :D

Still don't know why it took me so long to realize it.. -_-